# Receiving version field error when testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jestjs

I'm doing a test on a project using Jest.

This is the code for testing:

```
describe("POST /", () => {
    let token;
    let title;
    let genre;
    let dailyRentalRate;

    const exec = async () => {
      genre = await new Genre({
        name: "abcde",
      }).save();

      return await request(server)
        .post(config.get("URI") + "/movies")
        .set("x-auth-token", token)
        .send({ title, genre, numberInStock: 1, dailyRentalRate });
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
      token = new User().generateAuthToken();
      title = "abcdefg";
      dailyRentalRate = 4.2;
    });

    it("should save the movie if it is valid", async () => {
      const res = await exec();

      console.log(genre);

      console.log(res.body.error.details);

      // const movie = await Movie.find({ title });

      // expect(res.status).toBe(StatusCodes.OK);
      // expect(movie).not.toBeNull();
    });

  });
```

The models are following:

Genre:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const genreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 5,
    maxLenght: 50,
  },
});

const Genre = mongoose.model("Genre", genreSchema);
module.exports = { Genre, genreSchema };
```

Movie:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { genreSchema } = require("./genre");

const Movie = mongoose.model(
  "Movie",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 255,
    },
    genre: {
      type: genreSchema,
      required: true,
    },
    numberInStock: {
      type: Number,
      min: 0,
      max: 255,
      required: true,
    },
    dailyRentalRate: {
      type: Number,
    },
  })
);

module.exports = { Movie };
```

When I test this suite, I receive the following error:

[image: Jest Error]

Why am I receiving this error and how to solve it?

Comment: What error? They're just logs. Your test doesn't have an assertion to fail.

Comment: That is correct because I left the assertion out. If I had left the assertion, it would be what you see commit out.

Comment: Then [edit] the question with a [mre] that actually recreates a problem. Note code and outputs are _all text_ and should be presented as such.